# transmit my current location from my android app to my other android app after clicking on a button using google maps api In android studio

Tags: android, geolocation, location

How can I transmit my current location from my android app to my other android app after clicking on a button using Google Maps API in Android Studio where the map then shows the shortest route to the origin location of the clickers app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in a cloud database and give access to the db to both phones